# Painting on Windows Forms Control with System.Drawing.Graphics

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, controls, paint

I am totally new to this, I am working on a Windows Forms appliction in C# and would like to create a "LevelMeter", that is in my idea a ProgressBar with the upper left part covered by a triangle having the color of the Forms background. So basically I just would like to cover the upper left part to imitate a level meter, like VLC Players volumen control, or similar.

My problem is, how do I paint on the *Control* itself? I would like to create a UserControl and add to my project when it is done. I can paint on the Form using SolidBrush and FillPolygon, but the MSDN Library notes on ProgressBar.Paint event: "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code." So is there any way to paint on a Control?

---

OK: The "Never give up experimenting" principle is always true, here's my solution:

I made a custom LevelMeter : Control and use the FillPolygon method to draw the triangles of the LevelMeter, in my case there are only 8 different values ranging from 0 to 7, so I paint the 7 'sections' of the LevelMeter.

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        if (this.valueNew > valueOld)
        {
            // increase, paint with green
            this.CreateGraphics().FillPolygon(new SolidBrush(Color.LawnGreen), new Point[] { p2Old, p3Old, p3New, p2New });
        }

        else
        {
            // decrease, paint with BackColor
            this.CreateGraphics().FillPolygon(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), new Point[] { p2New, p3New, p3Old, p2Old });
        }
    }
```

To avoid 'flashing' that would result from clearing and repainting the LevelMeter every time the value changes, I only repaint the sections that need to be added (green) or removed (BackColor of the form).

Comment: You should answer your own question if you found a good solution for you.

Comment: Try setting `DoubleBuffered` to true if it is not, it's a property of `Control` (and thus `ProgressBar`).

Comment: I have set the DoubleBuffered to true, it keeps flashing. I need to make up my custom control from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're wanting to override `OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)` in your custom control. This will give you access to the `System.Drawing.Graphics` (through `e.Graphics`) object that you use to do custom painting on your control.

[Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) gives you access to a *ton* of methods you can use to do the painting you need.

Example:

```
public class MyControl : Control { 
  // ...
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) { 
    base.OnPaint(e); // Important - makes sure the Paint event fires
    using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3)) { 
      e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for submitting your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, overriding OnPaint, doesn't paint any shape on the ProgressBar. :(